# Error while trying to connect 2 pcs in lan

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet

I'm trying to connect two PCs in a local network and I am having difficulties. Some information about my setup:

1. **pc1:** OS GNU/Linux  Mageia
2. **pc2:** OS GNU/Linux  Debian

pc1 pings to pc2 with no problem, but pc2 ping to pc1 fails. This is the out console in pc2->

**data for pc2**:

```
ping -I eth0 100.10.2.104

PING 100.10.2.104 (100.10.2.104) from 100.10.2.103 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 100.10.2.104 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5040ms
```

**other data**:

```
    netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         100.10.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
100.10.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0


ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:100.10.2.103  Bcast:100.10.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

**data for pc1**:

```
ping -I eth0 100.10.2.103
```

ping ok

```
netstat -rn
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         100.10.2.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp2s0
    100.10.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp2s0

   ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  
              inet addr:100.10.2.104  Bcast:100.10.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

We have done several things including `sysctl -w net.apv4.ipforward=1` and `sysctl -w net.apv4.ipforward=0` on both computers and nothing all the same

What could be my mistake that causes pc2 not to receive the packages?

thanks for reading and apologize for my bad English

Comment: I would say you might be pinging some completely different host. Have you tried to use traceroute to see? Have you checked the arp table and compared the MAC address? are you 100% sure they are connected on the same LAN? Have you checked if PC1 has firewall and drop ICMP packets?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but reconfigure all using the 10.x.x.x envez had and now the two pcs ping well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be the usual local network address - they usually start with 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/16 or 192.168.0.0/16.  100.10.2.103 & 104 goes to some Verizon server in Kansas & New Jersey respectively.  Maybe your local network start with 10 instead of 100?

Comment: I just changed the number, for any of the mencionastes 10.x.x.x and that works for me thank you very much

Comment: reconfigure all using the 10.x.x.x